# Logging injection for flex/actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, logging, flex4, trace, code-injection

Is it possible to trace every single method call in flex/actionscript by injecting logging statements some way? Like how it's possible in C# using PostSharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using Vizzy Tracer. It will create a special mm.cfg file to configure the stacktrace output in the Flash Player so you can see every method call throughout the execution of the application plus a bunch of other nifty debugging features.

Description from the google code site:

Vizzy Flash Tracer shows debug trace of SWF files without adding any extra code. It works in Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome, Safari, Flash IDE, Adobe AIR and other places where trace statements exist. Vizzy is cross-platform and has all features that a developer requires for a comfortable and fast debugging.

http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/

Comment: I just seem to get a lot of "Error: Request for resource at xmlsocket://localhost:4444 by requestor" prints... Any idea what I might do wrong?

Comment: Are you running a local port server on 4444? If so, can you confirm/deny whether the connection to the port server is occuring? Add some server side log statements to see where the xmlsocket connection might be failing. Also, you may want to move this into a new question since its not directly related to logging injection.

Comment: I'm not running a local port server. I thought Vizzy was using 4444 for the communication. This only happens when I check the option "Trace all executed methods." in Vizzy. SOSMax works as usual when I don't check this i Vizzy but when I check this in Vizzy SOSMax also displays it.